# Can Android Device Monitor run as root automatically

Tags: android, adb, device, android-virtual-device

While developing in Android Studio on Windows, every now and then I have to check the database on my testing device. To pull it I use Android Device Manager. Through adb I granted access permissions to `/data/data/xx.xxx.xxx/` folders, but read and write permissions to `/data/data/xx.xxx.xxx/databases` folder and its files I have to grant every few minutes.
I'm giving grants with `chmod 777` command while running *adb*.

Is there a way to set things up that I can have constant read and write grants to the databases folder and its files?

Answer (score 0):

You can root the phone or use an emulator. Emulator files (including sqlite db) are easily accessible via DDMS without any permission. It also has a neat little download button which you can use to download db on your computer .

Comment: My phone is already rooted. I cannot use emulator because my computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology which is needed to run it.